# Can't access to cups web config UI on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: server, printing

I need to enable the office server also as a print server, with the printer connected via usb, but I'm having the exact same problem described in [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2246106).

CUPS is running, it's listening on port 631, it's enabled to be accessed from anywhere in the local network, and if I do `curl localhost:631` (or `curl 192.168.0.28:631`, the server's IP) it returns the web page to the console. Also, if I do `telnet localhost 631` (or `telnet 192.168.0.28 631`) from the server's console it tries to connect (connection is NOT refused, so the port IS open).

I'm trying to connect from a Windows machine, and I'm using a tool called `tcping.exe` to check whether port 631 is open. It seems that this port is not accessible.

Please help, I'm running out of ideas :S

EDIT:

I installed the printer on another machine (not the server) and it's working fine, so maybe it's a conflict with another service in the server. The server is running Apache2, MySQL, iRedMail mail server... I don't remember what else.

Comment: This seems to be a windows specific question - maybe running firewall on your client?

Comment: No, it's server related :S. I've edited the question to clarify it.